# What happened to 5.25" hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive

They could've provided much more storage space without resorting to using helium and extra efforts of compacting size of blocks and they fit any common PC case.

Why have we left with 3.5"? There is no problem for the industry to support multiple sizes as now we can have in a common PC: 3.5" HDD, 2.5" SSD, M2 SSD etc

I'd really appreciate having 20-ish HDD taking place in one of my 5.25" slots, enterprises could've used them too, why don't they make them anymore?

Comment: [Centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force) happened. ;)

Comment: You would buy one.  Now find a few million other users who also would buy them and a manufacturer might be interested.  So what is the benefit you would tout in your sales pitch to them?

Comment: Weight and volume, which also affects power.  FYI before there was the 5.25", there were 8" and 14" form factors, but such drives were rarely used with PCs.

Comment: I want a 10k RPM Winchester stack... why can't I find one?  ;)

Comment: @DanielB I'm thinking that now as SSDs replace all fast access operations, 5.25 drives will just rotate slower and people will be okay with it as the drives will be used purely for storage at that point and the only thing that will matter is dollars per TB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel B commented, one of the reasons why physically large drives are a problem is the centrifugal force. The larger the diamereter of the disk, the more force is excerted onto the disk as it spins. This will have to be countered by a thicker plate to increase durability, but this is not a linear increase, as the disk will also have to support its own mass, thus reducing the overall available volume inside.

There is also a limit of the read speed: as the sector moves faster due to the laws of geometry and an increasing radius, the head will have to move faster to keep up. No sure if this is a real bottleneck today, but it is certainly something to keep in mind.

Lastly, there is the fact that 5.25 is a formfactor that isn't that common anymore.

For solid state memory, 5.25 makes a lot more sense, as there are no moving parts that have to be scaled accordingly, but seeing as this would have a very limited application, I doubt it offers much return of investment for the manufacturers.

Comment: >5.25 is a formfactor that isn't that common anymore - that is exactly what I wanted to know why that happened

Comment: *"There is also a limit of the read speed:..."* -- You're making up a bogus reason.  The heads do not have to *"move faster to keep up"*.  If that was truly an issue, then there wouldn't be 10K RPM drives.  *"there is the fact that 5.25 is a formfactor that isn't that common anymore"* -- Every CD, DVD, and Blu-ray drive I've seen uses the 5.25" form factor (except for the slim drives).

Comment: @sawdust 10k disk (all?) have small platters, precisely because of the issues he mentioned (force, speed). So I wouldn't call it bogus. Unfortunately, I don't have the vocabulary to precisely describe the speed issue.

Comment: @Protheus We can't possibly know the reason.

Comment: "The head will have to move faster to keep up"? _What?_ Do you think the heads move around in a circle? The only moving the heads do is to or from the center of the drive, to access different tracks. If you mean the data rate will change, sure, but it does that now and for over ten years we've used "zone bit recording", which mitigates that. Your notion about platter strength to overcome centrifugal force is also bogus; that is far from the limiting factor.

Answer (score 3):

The most important factor in storage capacity is density - magnetic flux changes per unit area on the recording surface.

To increase that, you have to make the magnetic domains smaller. To do that the heads must fly closer to the surface. That demands that you make the surfaces smoother, flatter, more consistent, to avoid catastrophic head crashes.

Also the platters would need to be stronger - not so much because of centrifugal force (they are far stronger than they need to be for that) but to resist "flutter", up-and-down warping, as they spin. Flutter is caused partly by aerodynamic forces, which of course will increase if the platter has more surface area.

The smaller the platter, the easier that all is. It's easier to make a small thing that is "flat" and "rigid" to within some dimensional limit of variance than a larger thing that's flat and rigid to the same limit.

So modern head flight height would be more difficult to achieve on a 5-1/4 form factor. So much so that the increased surface area would result in lower data density, and it would be a net loss in capacity and reliability - unless you spent a lot more $ per byte.

The other factors like size, weight, heat, etc., could be dealt with if it made economic sense to do so. But it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

I think everyone is missing the potential of all of that volume. Inspired by the idea that SATA SSDs are mostly empty space, you could fill the entire volume of a 5.25” bay with 2.5” or underclocked/RAID NVMe drives (for thermal reasons this is slightly tricky), and get a minimum of 6-12 of those suckers inside the volume of a 5.25” bay. Suddenly you have dozens of terabytes of storage in a single bay.
What say you now?

Comment: https://www.newegg.com/nimbus-data-dc-100tb/p/2U3-002M-00004 - a 100Tb SSD in a 3.5". 3.5" SATA mounts are standard for servers, so they just stick SSD in this case.